# Filtering records from database table to be view and update

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to pull out records from database and display it on my php form for users to update it. In my database table, there's a column named stage. Under stage, there are foundation, intermediate and advance. Here's an example of it:

[Valid XHTML http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/2461/databasei.png](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/2461/databasei.png).
[Valid XHTML http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/profileint.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/profileint.png/).

So when i press the foundation button in my php form(2nd picture), only records where theirs stage are foundation, will be shown on the list(together with their name, contact number, email and student ID)
Is there any way that i can do that

Comment: What button are you talking about? Are you using a datatable library, does it have built-in filtering ability?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't specific enough. I've edit my question and also put my interface. 
Ermm, i don't know what is a datatable library.
Sorry i'm new in this.

Comment: You need to show your code, and how you've tried to solve this problem. We don't write your code for you.

Comment: I know and i'm not asking for solutions. I'm asking if there's any any way i could do that. Cause i've been seaching how to filter the records for the past 2 hours but none of them is what i need.

Comment: The answer is "Yes, there's a way to do it". But if you don't show what you've got, it's hard to provide more details, like where to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<?php
  $stage = $_GET['stage'];
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM {$tablename} WHERE stage=:stage';

  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname', $user, $pass);
  try {
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array(':stage', db->quote($stage)));
    foreach($statement->fetchAll() as $row) {
      // Do things here.
    }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Do you mind explaining to me this line:"catch (PDOException $e) "

Comment: It's part of the syntax of the `try` statement, used for detecting errors that happen during a block. Look it up in your PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include('connect-db2.php');

    // get results from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players2 WHERE stage = 'foundation'") 
            or die(mysql_error());  

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>S/N</th> <th>Student_ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Contacts No.</th> <th>Email</th><th>Stage</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['student_id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['contact_no'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['stage'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="edit2.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="delete2.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
?>
```